# How can i detect device orientation even if the orientation is locked

Tags: ios, uikit

I used magnometer but its values is always different.. I want to detect when the user device is horizontal mean in landscape position and on specific posting want to perform some action.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.swift inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function put the below code :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

then inside the AppDelegate put the following function:

```
func rotated() {
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        print("Landscape")
    }

    if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

hope it will work for you ... :)

Comment: But i think this will only work if user device is not locked for orientation

Comment: check it ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936205/how-to-programatically-check-if-orientation-is-locked-on-ios-swift

Comment: I don't want to detect phone's View orientation.. I want to detect orientation of phone it self.....i mean if phone is horizontal i perform some action....i get some values with magnetometer but these are values of magentic field and keep on changing according to envoirment